# SQL Profiler (SQL Server 2000), how to filter only my activities?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-profiler

We have a big system with several hundred concurrent users so sql profiler gives a bit too much information without appropriate filters. I'd like to see what SQL commands are run under my account and my account only. With account I mean the username I use to log in to the system. These user names are stored in a regular database table and thus can't as such be entered to any filter in sql profiler, I guess? But every user that logs in might have some unique id anyway even thou we all use the same SQL login/user?

So, the question is mostly how to get that unique value and which filter to use? Or is there any way to see this and only this in sql profiler?

Answer (score 24):

You should be able to get the **hostname** of the machine connecting to SQL server. In the **Trace Properties/Event Section** tab, tick the **Show all Columns** option then in **Column Filters** you can specify **HostName**.

If you want to know the hostname of a machine you are using then at the command prompt type `hostname`

Comment: Hi , this is not working in SQL Server 2012 , do you have any idea why ? , i filtered only my hostname.. but it seems that the hostname of IIS server is the who called in sql server profiler.

Answer (score 3):

Each appilcation, which connects to the SQL Server, has a unique host id (the value returned by the `HOST_ID()` function), and you can filter on it. Of course, first you have to connect to the database from your application, in order to get your host id.

The host id can also be found in the `hostprocess` column of the `sysprocesses` system table. And in Profiler it is called `ClientProcessId`.